# How to count amount of cars in the end of the road in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am moddeling an intersection and need to count amount of cars in the end of the road in Anylogic.

I know, that block CarMoveTo counts this value, but how to show this value on the graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a variable of type Integer named `v_Counter`, inital value 0
2. in the `CarMoveTo` block's "On exit" action, write `v_Counter++;`
3. plot the variable in a chart of your liking

Note that this code is executed for every car exiting the logic block, it is your responsibility to ensure this matches with exiting the road.

If you don't know how to plot variables, pls do *all* the step-by-step tutorials, they cover this and a ton more :)